# Как заблокировать уже выбранные номера из списка, массив выбранных номеров у меня есть, что с ним делать и как его применить?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, list, vuex

У меня есть вопрос, как заблокировать уже выбранные номера из списка, массив выбранных номеров у меня есть, что с ним делать и как его применить?

```
                    <select class="form-control" v-model="sortItem">
                      <option
                        v-for="item in 30"
                        v-bind:key="item"
                        v-bind:value="item"
                        v-text="item"
                        class="form-control"
                      ></option>
                    </select>
```

Вот массив

```
UF_SORT [ 13, 18, 24 ]
```

Нужно по исходя из этого массива заблокировать и сделать серыми цифры в выпадающем списке.
Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаясь на массив, который содержит `id` выбранных пунктов из списка, вы можете
для каждого `<option>` проверить есть ли его `id` в списке выбранных, как:

`UF_SORT.includes(id)`

и назначить в зависимости от этого атрибуту `disabled` значение

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      UF_SORT:[ 13, 18, 24 ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkDisable(id) {
      return this.UF_SORT.includes(id)
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select class="form" v-model="UF_SORT" multiple style="height: 100pt">
    <option v-for="item in 30" v-bind:key="item" v-bind:value="item" v-text="`Пункт - ${item}`" :disabled="checkDisable(item)"></option>
  </select>
  <hr>
    {{UF_SORT}}
</div>
```

Пример с инициализацией списка выбранных элементов при загрузке:

```js
// выбранные элементы, эти данные могут быть получены из API
const sortList = [ 13, 18, 24 ]

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      UF_SORT:[],
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    // инициализируем функцию
    this.getSortList()
  },
  methods: {
    checkDisable(id) {
      return this.UF_SORT.includes(id)
    },
    getSortList() {
      // здесь ваша функция получения списка выбранных элементов
      // ExpertAdvice.getListSortNumberProjectsAdvice(this.$route.params.id)
      //  .then( ({ data }) => { this.UF_SORT= data; } );
      this.UF_SORT = sortList // сторонние данные заносим в UF_SORT(демонстрация)
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select class="form" v-model="UF_SORT" multiple style="height: 100pt">
    <option v-for="item in 30" v-bind:key="item" v-bind:value="item" v-text="`Пункт - ${item}`" :disabled="checkDisable(item)"></option>
  </select>
  <hr>
    {{UF_SORT}}
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, за ответ! Буду пробовать)

Comment: в этой функции вероятно нужен return

    `checkDisable(id) {`
      `this.UF_SORT.includes(id)`   
 `},`

    `checkDisable(id) {`     `return  this.UF_SORT.includes(id)`
`},`

Comment: для лучшего восприятия, добавил

Comment: Я написал вот такую функцию, что бы получить массив чисел и добавить его в 
`data() {`
`return {`
 `UF_SORT: [ ]`  
  `}`
`}`


        `getSortList() {`
     `ExpertAdvice.getListSortNumberProjectsAdvice(this.$route.params.id).then(`
        `({ data }) => {`
           `this.UF_SORT= data;`
        `}`
      `);`
    `}`,

Где лучше вызвать функцию `getSortList`, что бы при загрузке у меня сразу добавлялся массив использованных чисел с сервера?

Comment: Если `SPA` в `mounted` хуке, если `SSR` в `created` хуке, в любом случае трудно дать однозначный ответ, не видя вашей текущей реализации

Comment: да у меня `SPA` и я в хуке `mounted` пишу функцию, но она не вызывается почему-то.
`getSortList() {` `ExpertAdvice.getListSortNumberProjectsAdvice(this.$route.params.id).then( ({` `data }) => { this.UF_SORT = data; } ); }`

Comment: Поместите вашу функцию `getSortList` в `methods` и в `mounted` вызовите как `this.getSortList()`

Comment: В ответ добавил пример простенький

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Боевая задача выполнена, заказчик доволен. Проблема была в том, что я неправильно добавлял данные с сервера в массив. Данные приходят в обЪекте, а я запихивал их в `UF_SORT: [ ]` - массив
this.UF_SORT = data.UF_SORT сработало))) Надо было из обекта данных вытащить массив UF_SORT

Answer (score 1):

```
       <select class="form-control" v-model="sortItem">
                      <option
                        v-for="item in 30"
                        v-bind:key="item"
                        v-bind:value="item"
                        v-text="item"
                        class="form-control"
                        :disabled="arr.includes(item)"
                      ></option>
                    </select>
```